# cannot find document just created in a trigger

Tags: triggers, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have the following issue.
We use the OBI framework of MarkLogic
I use a trigger in the database to monitor incomming sensor data.
As soon as a new OBI source is loaded I check some stuff.
If I find something I create an "Alert" object.
Then I would like to use that object the generate a"payload" message to send out to mobile devices...

Now trigger works.
In the trigger I use a xdmp:eval with a different transcaction to make sure I can use the document created in the same trigger code...
BUT if I search for the newly created object it cannot be found...

Can I create a document and use it in the same trigger code?

I am afraid it is hard to create a minimal working example here but this is a try:

Relevant trigger code:

```
(: fire trigger ALWAYS :)
let $_ := xdmp:log(fn:concat('TP-SENSORTRIGGER-ACTION : Source ', $trgr:uri, ' triggers base rule...')) 
(: create alert object plus link to source :)
let $object-id := xdmp:eval(concat('
    xquery version "1.0-ml";
    import module namespace scl = "http://example.com/sccs/lib" at "/lib/sccss-lib.xqy";

    declare variable $source-id external;

    let $object-id := scl:create-alert-object($source-id)
    let $_ := xdmp:log("***** test *****")      
    return $object-id 
    '), (xs:QName('source-id'), $source-id),
    <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><isolation>different-transaction</isolation></options>)
let $_ := xdmp:log($object-id)
(: create payload from alert object :)
(:let $payload := scl:create-payload-from-alert-object($object-id)
:)
let $object := obj:find-object($object-id)
let $_ := xdmp:log($object)
```

The function to create the OBI object is in a lib. I can share if needed.
I have added aa log line "test" and "test B" to make sure I use the proper triggers. And to make sure they are rebuild on deploy in app-specific.rb.

Then from the logs it is clear the object cannot be found:

```
2015-10-20 15:33:02.860 Info: example-app: ******** Ingest transform Started ***************
2015-10-20 15:33:04.196 Info: TaskServer: TP-SENSORTRIGGER /marklogic.solutions.obi/source/81a3591a-a885-4f85-a781-b066e706ff41.xml was created, start trigger action...
2015-10-20 15:33:04.291 Info: TaskServer: TP-SENSORTRIGGER-ACTION : Source /marklogic.solutions.obi/source/81a3591a-a885-4f85-a781-b066e706ff41.xml triggers base rule...
2015-10-20 15:33:07.267 Info: TaskServer: ***** test B *****
2015-10-20 15:33:07.268 Info: TaskServer: ***** test *****
2015-10-20 15:33:07.273 Info: TaskServer: 4d1fd4e4-2911-40b0-848c-ccf8eaa39229
2015-10-20 15:33:07.277 Info: TaskServer:
```

After the trigger has run I can of course find the object with id 4d1fd4e4-2911-40b0-848c-ccf8eaa39229 from the QC.

So this has to do with the transaction model of MarkLogic I guess.

So again the question: Why cant I find the object I just created in a xdmp:eval ?

Answer (score 0):

### SOLUTION

It turned out you have to wrap ALL functions downstream in a xdmp:eval() for this to work.

```
(: fire trigger ALWAYS :)
let $_ := xdmp:log(fn:concat('TP-SENSORTRIGGER-ACTION : Source ', $trgr:uri, ' triggers base rule...')) 
(: create alert object plus link to source :)
let $object-id := xdmp:eval(concat('
    xquery version "1.0-ml";
    import module namespace scl = "http://example.com/sccs/lib" at "/lib/example-lib.xqy";

    declare variable $source-id external;
    declare variable $actions external;
    declare variable $lastseen external;

    let $object-id := scl:create-alert-object($source-id,$actions,$lastseen)

    return $object-id 
    '), (xs:QName('source-id'), $source-id,xs:QName('actions'), $actions,xs:QName('lastseen'), $lastseen),
    <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><isolation>different-transaction</isolation></options>)
let $_ := xdmp:log($object-id)
(: create payload from alert object :)
(:let $payload := scl:create-payload-from-alert-object($object-id)
:)
let $payload := xdmp:eval(concat('
    xquery version "1.0-ml";
    import module namespace scl = "http://example.com/sccs/lib" at "/lib/sccss-lib.xqy";

    declare variable $object-id external;

    let $payload := scl:create-payload-from-alert-object($object-id)

    return $payload 
    '), (xs:QName('object-id'), $object-id),
    <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><isolation>different-transaction</isolation></options>)
let $_ := xdmp:log("************* PAYLOAD ****************")
let $_ := xdmp:log($payload)
(: send alert to middletier :)

let $result := xdmp:eval(concat('
    xquery version "1.0-ml";
    import module namespace scl = "http://example.com/sccs/lib" at "/lib/sccss-lib.xqy";

    declare variable $payload external;

    let $res := scl:send-alert-notification($payload)

    return $res 
    '), (xs:QName('payload'), $payload),
    <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><isolation>different-transaction</isolation></options>)
let $_ := xdmp:log("************* RESULT ****************")
let $_ := xdmp:log($result)
```

This is not clear from [the documentation of the xdmp:eval()](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:eval) function :

> " When set to different-transaction, the statement is evaluated in a
>   separate transaction from the one in which it is called, making those
>   updates available to subsequent expressions in the calling statement
>   (assuming the calling statement is an update statement; if the calling
>   statement is not an update, then subsequent expressions will see the
>   version of the database at the system timestamp when the calling
>   statement begins its evaluation)."